# Postfix on eventual consistency storage

Tags: postfix-mta, s3fs

I'm trying to set up a Postfix-based mail system with mailboxes on a s3fs mount. Every time I receive an email, Postfix seems to have problems adding the file to the maildir and shows errors like this:

```
Nov 13 21:02:25 clay postfix/virtual[19844]: 281181FF05E: to=<unai@example.com>, relay=virtual, delay=1.8, delays=0/0.02/0/1.7, dsn=4.2.0, status=deferred (maildir delivery failed: create maildir file ///data/mailboxes/example.com/unai/new/1699909344.V21I68M190240.clay: Operation not supported)
```

I got around similar issues with Courier running on this server by setting IMAP_USELOCKS=0 on /etc/courier/imapd

I've tried similar things on Postfix by setting different values to deliver_lock_delay and virtual_mailbox_lock but it's still throwing the same "Operation not supported" error.

I've been looking at [Postfix source](https://github.com/vdukhovni/postfix/blob/master/postfix/src/virtual/maildir.c#L235) and I'm not sure if the issue is due to some special file attributes not supported by the s3mount or just because it's too slow and it's failing some sort of test.

This same server can receive send and receive email with mailboxes on a local disk (not on the s3fs mount).

I've tried the s3fs mount with and without local cache folder -- and I get the same results.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure this is eventual consistency related -- rather it seems like some locking is not supported.  You can verify this via `strace` and looking for the failing system call.  Can postfix disable these locks?